# Can I specify that a DACPAC can only run if a database does or does not exist?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

We have a solution composed of two SQL Database projects:

- The **model_create** project contains "dynamic" objects we don't consider part of the core schema and post deployment scripts that only run when creating a new database. **model_create** references the **model_core** project.
- The **model_core** project contains core database objects and updates reference data that change over time.

Is there any way to specify **model_create** should only run if the database does not exist and must be created? Those scripts are already idempotent and won't insert dupes, but there are tens of thousands of inserts to ignore.

Is there any way to specify **model_core** must not create a new database because it lacks some of the startup data we only want to insert once? Sort of like the opposite of the publish profile setting that says "always create new database".

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what you are doing, it isn't clear which project references which, that being said the post deploy script is only run from the dacpac being deployed - any referenced dacpacs don't get their post deploy scripts run - does that help?

It sounds that if you have a one off script is would be better to just run the script outside of the ssdt deployment. I would still keep it in an ssdt project but just do the deploy of your main project and then deploy the script by itself.

Another approach would be to make those scripts idenpotent, I've done it before using the scripts on, if you know c# you can get the individual inserts and do something with them. The something depends on what your setup is exactly.

Hope it helps!

Ed

Comment: Yes, we're trying to isolate all the "one off" stuff into the model_create project that should only run when creating a new database. This includes bulk data we insert only once and a couple of "dynamic" tables. These are tables with columns that get added based on user input. I know it isn't ideal, but this is the situation as it exists. Keeping those tables in the "core" project kept dropping the custom columns, so I decided to isolate those "dynamic" objects into the "create" project so they are only run when creating a new database.